# Detect Button Press in FBLoginView

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I need to fire a certain method as soon as the user clicks the "Login" option on the FBLoginView. Once the window displaying the login fields disappears, I figured that viewWillAppear would fire, but it doesn't. Does anyone know of a way to detect when the FBLoginView disappears?

This is the specific window I'm referring to if the question was a bit vague:
[image]

Comment: Are you using facebook framework? If so why can't you use their successful login delegates? http://blog.grio.com/2013/01/fbloginview-facebook-authentication-made-easy-with-sdk-3-x.html

Comment: @SamBudda Yes sir I am, but for some reason `- (void)facebookLoginSuccess` won't fire, it's odd.